# My question is "Is CMS going to replace the place of coding?"

Tags: content-management-system

For the last few days, I have heard about the thing, "CMS" (Content Management System). But I am confused about the question, **"Is CMS taking the place of coding?"** Actually, I just started learning to coding. So, should I continue to learn coding or shift to CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on StackOverflow Azmain!

As a professional developer I can tell you that learn coding is always a good choice.

If you want to create a website there are a ton of ways to achieve what you want, you can use CMS that are basically software that other programmers develop and maintain for free (this is the soul of Open Source community).There are a lots of CMS you can find online (Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, Magento, etc..) and they do something better to others so you need to pick the right CMS for your usage.

If you want to learn coding I suggest you to start from YouTube and follow some tutorial based on what you want to do (yes, I mean bingie watching as much videos you can!).
Someone says to start from PHP, others say to learn first Python or Javascript.. but it's all about you. My suggestion is to start from Python or Javascript if this is the first experience in programming (IMHO: actually Python is the perfect choice due to a low learning curve and an easy setup for your development environment).

If you want only to go fast and create custom websites there is a common path:

- HTML, CSS (starting point lol)
- Javascript (no jQuery... in 2020 is dead!)

  - Angular or ReactJS or Vue as a framework, lots of companies are searching for frontend developers that know at least a framework between these

There are other things to understand like Javascript ES6, tools as webpack or grunt and other things that will be more clear when you will deepen.
At this point you are a so-called Frontend Developer.
To go for a FullStack you need some server programming skills and you can learn NodeJS and Express and then include some libraries to easily create custom APIs on REST or even on GraphQL, actually I use this one for all my projects that need an API to use on frontend, mobile app, IoT devices etc.

So to finally answer your question, no CMS will not replace coding because at least we need to code the CMS itself!
(This question is similar to "Will AI replace coders or developers?")

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the most suitable answer that I wanted. I am going through the basics at first (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). I want to do FullStack. So I will also learn other languages when I finish the basics. Once again, Thanks.

Comment: Basically a fullstack developer is a developer that is a frontend and a backend developer at the same time. Probably using the same language to code it all from server to clients and actually Javascript is so hot! The community around is incredible and surely you will find some resource/video/guide/tutorial online to follow and start code.

Comment: I know what full-stack developer is?

Answer (score 2):

At first set your goal what you want to be in future?

Website Developer Or Mobile Application Developer

you're talking about CMS then it's obvious you are on the side of Web

```
if you're good in programming , can make logics on your own and good understanding of database then go with Backend-Development.
PHP or ASP.NET (choose one)
then go to the frameworks like Laravel PHP
Most Trending  Framework right now is Js Frameworks like
• NodeJs 
• ExpressJs

If you're good in creativity and designing go with front-end developement
Learn 
HTML CSS SCSS Javascript jQuery
then go to the framworks like
ReactJS , AngulerJs (Choose one)
```

Then One Day you'll be a full-stack developer

Start Learn Coding so you can build your own CMS. 
If you stick with CMS there are many jobs but you'll be dependent to that CMS

Comment: That means I have to learn coding for what I want to do. Thanks